# Using lenses to compose functions

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses

Consider "composition" functions with the following (pseudo) signature:

```
(a1 -> a2 -> ... -> an -> r) -> 
(s -> ai) -> 
a1 -> a2 -> ... -> ai -> ... an -> r
where i in [1..n]
```

Of course we can't write what's above in Haskell, but here's a concrete example:

```
f4change3 :: 
  (a1 -> a2 -> a3 -> a4 -> r) -> 
  (s -> a3) -> 
  a1 -> a2 -> s -> a4 -> r
f4change3 f g x1 x2 x3 x4 = f x1 x2 (g x3) x4
```

As you can see, there's a collection of `n` functions for each function of arity `n`, so the number of functions we need grows quadratically with arity.

I could just write the ones I need, but firstly, I don't want to reinvent the wheel, so it would be nice to know if library has already done this. But also, whilst I have barely used lenses, I've read a bit about them, and this sort of problem seems right up their ally, but I'm not sure exactly how to do it. Some example code would be great if it's possible.

Comment: I don't understand the question ...

Comment: I think you're essentially asking about http://conal.net/blog/posts/semantic-editor-combinators

Comment: Can't you use *template Haskell* for that?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I guess so, but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel, and this just feels lensy, but I'm not exactly sure how to use them in this case.

Comment: There are lenses that act like Cona's semantic editor combinators, if you must use lens.  But I'd start bv looking at how they address the issue, because as far as I can tell, they do.

Comment: Bah, *Conal.  Didn't notice the typo in time to edit.

Comment: I've reread the article, but I'm still struggling to understand how the ideas he's presented generalise to functions of many arguments. Could you provide an example e.g. an implementation of 'f4change3' above?

Comment: Actually there are not quadratically many functions: `f4change3` works just fine on five- and more-argument functions. You only need one function per argument position.

Comment: @Clinton Re: "I'm struggling to understand how the ideas he's presented generalise to functions of many arguments". What is this "functions of many arguments" you speak of? I know not of such. This is partly a joke, and partly not: part of the zen of Haskell is embracing and internalizing the "functions take exactly one argument" worldview, and speaking of multi-argument functions only as an occasionally convenient shorthand for functions that return functions.

Comment: @DanielWagner your answer has made it very clear (as always). Thank you again. You win the tick mark!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, [Conal Elliott's semantic editor combinators](http://conal.net/blog/posts/semantic-editor-combinators) give a quite beautiful tool for writing these functions. Let's review just two of his combinators:

```
argument :: (a' -> a) -> ((a -> b) -> (a' -> b))
argument = flip (.)

result :: (b -> b') -> ((a -> b) -> (a -> b'))
result = (.)
```

In words: `argument` modifies a function's argument before the function is called, and `result` modifies a function's return value after it is called. (See the blog post itself for further intuition-bolstering explanations of these combinators.) Let's say we have a function with a type like

```
a1 -> a2 -> a3 -> a4 -> a5 -> b
```

and we want to change `a5`. Note that we can parenthesize this, of course:

```
a1 -> (a2 -> (a3 -> (a4 -> (a5 -> b))))
```

So if we want to reach `a5`, how should we reach into this structure? Well, we will do it by repeatedly reaching into the `result`, then acting on the `argument`: the result type of this function is `a2 -> (a3 -> (a4 -> (a5 -> b)))`, whose result is `a3 -> (a4 -> (a5 -> b))`, whose result is `a4 -> (a5 -> b)`, whose result is `a5 -> b`, whose argument is `a5`. This gives us the code directly:

```
arg5 :: (a5' -> a5)
     -> (a1 -> a2 -> a3 -> a4 -> a5  -> b)
     -> (a1 -> a2 -> a3 -> a4 -> a5' -> b)
arg5 = result . result . result . result . argument
```

Hopefully it is quite clear how to generalize this to modify other arguments: just vary the number of times you call `result`.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here is the real answer. If you don't want to just laugh and want to solve problem, you can go next way.

Your implementation can be shorten a little:

```
f4change3 ::
  (a1 -> a2 -> a3 -> a4 -> r) ->
  (s -> a3) ->
  a1 -> a2 -> s -> a4 -> r
f4change3 f g x1 x2 = f x1 x2 . g
```

This is not very useful and you can go full point-free (see my earlier answer).

I wish Haskell had named arguments so you can simply just write similar to `-XRecordWildCards`:

```
f4change3 ::
  ((a1 :: a1) -> (a2 :: a2) -> (a3 :: a3) -> (a4 :: a4) -> r) ->
  ((s :: s) -> a3) ->
  (a1 :: a1) -> (a2 :: a2) -> (s :: s) -> (a4 :: a4) -> r
f4change3 f g = f{ a3 = g{..}, .. }
```

For such particular cases when we want names of arguments be the same as names of type variables syntax can be even much-much shorter. But unfortunately we won't see such sweet features in nearest future (or ever).

But you asked about solution with lenses. You indeed can achieve something similar using lenses. Only thing you need to change in your type signatures is to represent arguments for `f` as data type with four fields. Here is complete code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import           Control.Lens (makeLenses, (%~))

data FArg a1 a2 a3 a4 = FArg
    { _a1 :: a1
    , _a2 :: a2
    , _a3 :: a3
    , _a4 :: a4
    }

makeLenses ''FArg

f4change3 ::
  (FArg a1 a2 a3 a4 -> r) ->
  (s -> a3) ->
  FArg a1 a2 s a4 -> r
f4change3 f g = f . (a3 %~ g)
```

Maybe some sophisticated solution using lenses is acceptable but here we at least achieve understandability (if you familiar with lenses of course). But usually nobody do this.

Answer (score -3):

This library is called `base`. And you don't even need to import anything, everything is already in `Prelude`. All you need is a little imagination and creativity. And then you can easily write your function in next way:

```
f4change3 ::
  (a1 -> a2 -> a3 -> a4 -> r) ->
  (s -> a3) ->
  a1 -> a2 -> s -> a4 -> r
f4change3 = flip . ((flip . ((.) .)) .)
```

After several years of training and reading such code you will fill yourself comfortable with such kind of code. And it will require only couple hours from you to understand what this implementation actually does. But guru Haskell programmers don't read implementations because everything is obviously clear from type.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Your implementation is just a point-free version of the `f4change` in the question. The OP is looking for a way to generalise it.

Comment: Someone doesn't get jokes and irony... You guys shouldn't be too serious here :)

Comment: Well, that isn't entirely fair: I was going to write a comment specifically about the second paragraph, but stopped myself in time :)

Comment: @duplode Well, the only thing I lied about is probably that several years of training is not enough :D After 4 years of learning Haskell I still cannot understand such point-free notations in finite amount of time...